# Cannot Load Tidyverse Package

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, tidyverse

I am running RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04.  In attempting to load the tidyverse package with library(tidyverse), I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
.onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
call: NULL
error: Function getThemeInfo not found in RStudio
```

getThemeInfo is a function in the rstudioapi package.  Besides re-installing the tidyverse and rstudioapi packages, I've tried deleting my .rstudio-desktop folder, as well as re-installing both R and RStudio.  Nothing has worked.  I can still load the component tidyverse packages separately so it's not fatal, but it is annoying.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try http://community.rstudio.com/ for general RStudio problems and fails.